# Entropy estimation from discrete variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to estimate conditional entropy of 3 variables using `pyitlib` package for python.
But i am encountering error

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from pyitlib import discrete_random_variable as drv

X=[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
Y=[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
Z=[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]

a=drv.entropy_conditional('X','Y','Z')
print(a)
```

The error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 518
    mask &= (ar1 != a)
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\testing.py", line 8, in <module>
    a=drv.entropy_conditional('X','Y','Z')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyitlib\discrete_random_variable.py", line 3495, in entropy_conditional
    fill_value_Alphabet_Y))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyitlib\discrete_random_variable.py", line 4689, in _map_observations_to_integers
    Fill_values = [L.transform(np.atleast_1d(f)) for f in Fill_values]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyitlib\discrete_random_variable.py", line 4689, in <listcomp>
    Fill_values = [L.transform(np.atleast_1d(f)) for f in Fill_values]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 257, in transform
    _, y = _encode(y, uniques=self.classes_, encode=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 110, in _encode
    return _encode_numpy(values, uniques, encode)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 53, in _encode_numpy
    % str(diff))
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [-1]
```

I am trying to find conditional mutual information between X,Y,Z(values given above) using the formula:

```
I(X;Y|Z)=H(X,Z)+H(Y,Z)-H(X,Y,Z)-H(Z)
```

The expected Conditional Mutual information value is= 0.011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method `entropy_conditional` is expecting an array, not strings, hence the error you receive. You can simply change the line to:

```
a = drv.entropy_conditional(X,Y,Z)
```

Documentation is available [here](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/)

Comment: `a=drv.entropy_joint(X,Z)
print(a)`

Comment: Tried to run this code. The error i am encountering, 

`ValueError: arg base not a positive real-valued scalar`

Comment: @NetranjitBorgohain that's a different method, but again it expects a different set of parameters `entropy_joint(X, base=2, fill_value=-1, estimator='ML', Alphabet_X=None,
                  keep_dims=False)` see [documentation](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/_modules/discrete_random_variable.html) for details

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to have been subsumed by a near-duplicate, please see [this repsponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402338/finding-conditional-mutual-information-from-3-discrete-variable/55426682#55426682) on how to compute conditional entropy.